# javascript animation sometimes works

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval

I'm trying to make pacman move without using jquery.animation because I want more control.  so I'm using setInterval, but it only works sometimes.  if you refresh enough, it will eventually "click on" and work fine, but if you refresh again, it won't work, it's here http://pacman.townsendwebdd.com if you want to look at it, thank you

```
//earlier in the code
this.moveInterval = setInterval(_this.move, 40, _this);

move: function(_this)
{
    if(_this.pause)//set to true for now
        return false;

    var horz = 0;
    var vert = 0;

    var dir = _this.dir;

    //set horizontal and vertical directions
    if(dir % 2 == 0)
        horz = dir - 1;
    else
        vert = dir - 2;

    _this.top += vert;
    _this.left += horz;

    $('#pacman').css('top', _this.top);
    $('#pacman').css('left', _this.left);
},
```

Comment: _but it only works sometimes._ It seems to "work" all the time for me, assuming "work" means that the pacman moves downward on the page.

Comment: yeah, you can use the arrow keys to change direction too, sometimes he just sits there and opens and closes his mouth, he should do both, move and eat
I think it works better with hard refresh verses clicking the refresh button (then is stops more often)

Comment: Do we need to see your commented-out code?

Comment: You're using jQuery AND Mootools? That's just wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix the problem, but I would recommend using [request animation frame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) instead of setInterval.

The other thing I think would be the problem (and I've been stung by this too) is that you're possibly trying to start the animation before the page has fully loaded. Try putting your code into a function and calling it with the [onload attribute of the body tag](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp).

Good luck!

Griffork.

Comment: I have everything in a $(document).ready(function(){}); call.  I will look in to the request animation frame, thank you
I guess I probably should be using canvas for this anyway

Comment: You marked my response as an answer, did you actually get it working? Your last comment made it sound like you were already doing the things I suggested :).

Comment: Also, in line 17 of your main, you should change the line `_this = this;` to `var _this = this` so that you're not creating a global variable called `_this` and in your move function (line 67 of pacman.js) you need to do boundary check on dir, because if you press any button that's not an arrow key then pacman goes flying around the screen XD.

Comment: ok, fair enough,  still not working.  looks like it only breaks sometimes when I hit F5 or click refresh.
I just figured I should give canvas and request animation frame a try

Comment: Ok, I'm just trying to make sure that you end up getting the answer to your problem, it's unlikely that people will come and try to answer this question since it's already marked as "answered". If you can I would recommend marking this question as unanswered (I don't know how to do that myself, I'm relatively new to the site). Worst case you might need to ask it again (but rephrase it so that you don't end up back here). Cheers and good luck! Griffork.